# Zebra ZPL Code 128 SSCC encodes the escape characters also

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I need to print a SSCC Code 128 barcode using Zebra ZPL. My problem is that the escape characters used are also encoded in the barcode, which should not happen.

Here is the code:

```
^FO50,960^BY3
^BCN,180,N,N,N,A
^FD>;>800{sscc}^FS
```

The sequence `>;>8`, which is the escape / control sequence, gets encoded in the barcode. So when I read the barcode with a scanner, I get: `>;>800xxxxxx....`

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are using Automatic mode (the last A in the `^BC` command).  That disables the escape sequences.  Use mode N (none) instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it worked. Please post it as an answer, so I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting this as an answer.  You are using Automatic mode (the A at the end of the `^BC` command).  Automatic mode disables escape sequences since it applies its own shift/latch logic.  Use mode N (None) to allow manually encoding the data.